# Unsigned field in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I was looking for a way to create a table with unsigned integer (I know I will have only positive integers, so why not to increase the range twofold). To create an integer field, I do:

```
create table funny_table(
    my_field bigint
);
```

So I thought that using `my_field bigint unsigned` will solve my problem, but syntax error tells me otherwise. Looking though the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html) tells nothing about unsigned integers. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Amazon Redshift doesn't support unsigned integer. As a workaround, we are using `numeric(20,0)` for `bigint unsigned` data. Here is an example.

```sql
create table funny_table(
    my_field numeric(20, 0)
);
insert into funny_table values ( 18446744073709551614 );
select * from funny_table;
       my_field
----------------------
 18446744073709551614
(1 row)
```

See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html) for the details of Numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, Redshift does not support `unsigned`. Given that, please take a closer at what you need to achieve.

`bigint` occupies 8 bytes giving you a range of -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

`numeric` occupies 128-bit (Variable, up to 128 bits) but offers a bigger range at the expense of memory.

I believe the idea behind using `unsigned` is doubling the range WITHOUT EXTRA EXPENSE TO STORAGE. So if you are comfortable with the highest positive value of `2^63 - 1` go with bigint and forget about the unsigned because it costs 8 bytes anyway.

If you have bigger positive integers go with `numeric(20, 0)` (or higher precision) but you need to be aware that it is still signed and occupies more than 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is running into the issue that they cant copy the unsigned int value from the source table:

You have to change the tupple mapping from previously:

```
("id", "int", "id", "int")
```

to

```
("id", "id", "decimal(20,0)")
```

We always had `null` values in our redshift cluster for the id. The change in the mapping changed this behaviour, which resulted in correctly copying the value from the source table.